# How can I inject options into an select tag inside the widget form?

Tags: plugins, widgets, jquery, ajax

I created a widget, that retrieves filenames from the database and am now trying to output the filenames as options in a select tag inside the admin widget menu(the form function in the widget class).

This is how it looks at the moment:

```
function form($instance) {
    ?> <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
               var data = {
            'action'  : 'clc_return_imagefilenames'
                    };
                    // send ajax request
                    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        // parse response and add slides
                    retrievedImagenames = JSON.parse(response);
                    for(var i = 0; i < retrievedImagenames.imagenamestoreturn.length; i++){
                            filename = retrievedImagenames.imagenamestoreturn[i]['filename'];
                            jQuery("<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'filenames' );?>").html('<option value="'+filename+'">'+filename+'</option>');
                        }
                    }); 
            });

                    </script>

        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'filenames' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'filenames' ); ?>" size="10" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1"></select>

        <?php
```

The plan is to get the filenames via AJAX (works, I tested it) and then append them to the select tag with jQuery.

The problem is, that nothing happens...and it is not a problem with the server or AJAX, filename is set, I can see the returned JSON objects in the console and I can even output them using jQuery. But it doesn't append them to the select tag and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your jQuery statement. You pass the `get_field_id` but without `#` it's looking for a `tag` not and `id`. The second thing is even if that worked, you would be replacing the contents with only one filename using `html` but you should adding to the list using `append`.

Here is a quick test to highlight the areas.

```
function form_test () {

  $field_id = 'test_xyz';

  ?><select id="<?php echo $field_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $field_id; ?>" size="10" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1"></select>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var data = ['fileA', 'fileB', 'fileC'];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var filename = data[i];
        jQuery( "#<?php echo $field_id; ?>").append('<option value="'+filename+'">'+filename+'</option>');
      }

  });
  </script><?php
}

add_filter ('the_content', function($content){  return $content.form_test(); });
```

Your code would end up looking more like

```
function form ($instance) {

  $field_id = $this->get_field_id( 'filenames' );

    ?><select id="<?php echo $field_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $field_id; ?>" size="10" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1"></select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var data = { 'action'  : 'clc_return_imagefilenames' };
        // send ajax request
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
          // parse response and add slides
          var retrievedImagenames = JSON.parse(response);
          for(var i = 0; i < retrievedImagenames.imagenamestoreturn.length; i++){
            var filename = retrievedImagenames.imagenamestoreturn[i]['filename'];
            jQuery( "#<?php echo $field_id; ?>").append('<option value="'+filename+'">'+filename+'</option>');
          }
        });
      });
    </script><?php
  }
```